# Python: ¿Como hago para comprobar si en una linea de un archivo de texto, en algun lugar, se puede detectar ciertas palabras?

Tags: python

Me explico, estoy intentando hacer un "lenguaje de programacion" con Python, la idea es la siguiente:

Hay un archivo de texto, que tiene este contenido en la linea 0 (seria la 1): `Print > Hola`
Y lo que quiero hacer, es que python detecte que en la linea 0, diga `Print >`  y omita eso una vez sepa que dice "Print > " y imprimir por pantalla el "Hola"

Codigo:

```
f = open("language/code.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
print(type(lines)) # Salida: list
f.close()
for i in lines:
    line = lines[i] # Aqui aparece un error, dice que i es un str y por lo tanto no puedo buscar una posicion en la lista, pero si pones un 0 (que es lo que hice) funciona.
    if ("Print > Hola" in lines):
        line -= line[:8] # Y aqui esta el error, mi idea seria restarle a la variable "line"... los primeros 8 caracteres de "line" en si, pero me aparece un error, diciendo que no puedo restar strings
        print(line)
```

Entonces... ¿Que hago para solucionarlo? (perdon si el codigo es pesimo, es lo que se me ocurrio)

Gracias de antemano.

Edit: Este es el codigo actualizado, ahora tengo otro problema, que es hacer que el if no dependa de que diga "Print > Hola":

```
f = open("primitive/code.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for line in lines:
    if ("Print > " in lines):
        line = line[8:].strip()
        print(line)
```

Codigo del archivo .txt:

```
Print > Hola
Print > Que tal?
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131888/discussion-on-question-by-skeletoos57-python-como-hago-para-comprobar-si-en-un).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un interprete tiene una estructura típica: leer la entrada, dividirla en tokens (variables, valores, instrucciones, etc.), validar y ejecutar la instrucción.

#### Lexer

El esqueleto de esta aplicación lo iniciamos con un lexer, que se encarga de tomar el archivo fuente y dividirlo en *tokens*, las partes elementales indivisibles del lenguaje, retornandolos luego uno a uno.

```
class Lexer:
    def __init__(self, archivo):
        self.archivo = open(archivo, "rt")
        self.linea = []

    def get_token(self):
        if not self.linea:
            self.linea = self.archivo.readline().split()
        return self.linea.pop(0) if self.linea else None
```

Esta clase debe encargarse de reconocer las cadenas, caracteres escapados, comentarios, etc. En este ejemplo mínimo, el lexer no reconoce más que palabras y valores.

#### Interprete

El interprete toma los tokens generados por Lexer y los "interpreta" o ejecuta.

Funciona así: se lee un token, que se interpreta como una instrucción, y la busca en la tabla de instrucciones.

De dicha tabla recupera la función encarga de procesar la instrucción y la llama, pasando el lexer como argumento para que la función pueda leer sus parámetros desde el fuente.

```
def interprete(archivo):
    lexer = Lexer(archivo)
    while True:
        token = lexer.get_token()
        if token is None:
            break  # Fin del archivo fuente

        if token in instrucciones:
            instrucciones[token](lexer)
        else:
            print(f"Instruccion no valida {token}")
            break
```

Esta es el diccionario que define todas las instrucciones reconocidas:

```
instrucciones = {
    "print": stmt_print,
    "time": stmt_time,
    "sqrt": stmt_sqrt
}
```

y las respectivas funciones que procesan cada instrucción:

```
def stmt_print(lexer):
    token = lexer.get_token() # >
    token = lexer.get_token() # Valor
    print(token)

def stmt_time(lexer):
    print(datetime.datetime.now())

def stmt_sqrt(lexer):
    valor = int(lexer.get_token())
    print(math.sqrt(valor))
```

#### Demo

*programa.txt*

```
print > Hola
print > 123
sqrt 5
time 
xyz
print > Esto no se ejecuta.
```

*código*

```
import datetime
import math


class Lexer:
    def __init__(self, archivo):
        self.archivo = open(archivo, "rt")
        self.linea = []

    def get_token(self):
        if not self.linea:
            self.linea = self.archivo.readline().split()
        return self.linea.pop(0) if self.linea else None


def stmt_print(lexer):
    token = lexer.get_token() # >
    token = lexer.get_token() # Valor
    print(token)

def stmt_time(lexer):
    print(datetime.datetime.now())

def stmt_sqrt(lexer):
    valor = int(lexer.get_token())
    print(math.sqrt(valor))

instrucciones = {
    "print": stmt_print,
    "time": stmt_time,
    "sqrt": stmt_sqrt
}

def interprete(archivo):
    lexer = Lexer(archivo)
    while True:
        token = lexer.get_token()
        if token is None:
            break

        if token in instrucciones:
            instrucciones[token](lexer)
        else:
            print(f"Instruccion no valida {token}")
            break


interprete("programa.txt")
```

produce:

```
Hola
123
2.23606797749979
2021-11-21 03:07:02.616924
Instruccion no valida xyz

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gracias! Esto definitivamente es mas practico que lo que he hecho :D

Comment: Eso si, no entendi lo de los tokens ¿Para que sirve obtenerlos? ¿Y que rol cumplen?